# The Meg...what was spat out?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-meg

When the second Meg is killed, it appeared to me that the Meg spit out a shark.  Was that a baby Meg for the sequel should this one do well?

Comment: That was just a shark that was eating the Meg from inside, then swam out of its mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unlikely.

Despite some sharks bearing their pups [inside them](https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/fish/discover/sharks/biology/), the pup wouldn't survive all the damage and casually swim out of it's mother by her mouth. The birth and digestive canals are not related. Megalodon are also [unknown](https://www.britannica.com/animal/megalodon) regarding whether they bear pups or lay them.

This was likely just a shark that started eating the Meg from the inside and then came out. I found it a very eerie, but great, shot, of how ruthless the ocean and the shark's species are.